# jquery formvalidation engine add method

Tags: jquery, ajax, validation

How to create a method that check if an email is valid, if the validator find an '@' sign?
(the input text is either name or email address only).

Comment: first of all always do form validation with server-side script

Comment: You mean if input contains @ then check for email validation otherwise check for name validation?

Comment: @PriyankPatel yes your right..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function checkMail(email){
    var filter  = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
    if (filter.test(email)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

checkMail('me@domain.com'); // return true or false if invalid.
```

This will check the e-mailaddress additionally if a valid domain is written.

me@something --> invalid
@something.com --> invalid
me@.com --> invalid
me@something.com --> valid

[Regular Expression Library -->](http://regexlib.com)

If you want to validate the mail address with jQuery Validation Engine, simply add:

```
data-validation-engine="validate[required,custom[email]]"
```

to the input field.

---

**Since Form Validation Engine 1.6.4**, there's the **possibility to add your own function** for validation: http://www.position-absolute.com/news/form-validation-engine-1-6-4/

You can replace the code in the example with this, then it should work:

```
<input value="" data-validation-engine="validate[required,funcCall[nameOrMail]]" class="text-input nameOrMail" type="text" name="req" id="req" />
```

JS (To your `<head>`):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("#formID").validationEngine({
        "nameOrMail": {
            "nname":"nameOrMail"
        }
    });
});

function checkMail(email){
    var filter  = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
    if (filter.test(email)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

function nameOrMail(){
    if($(".nameOrMail").val().indexOf('@') >= 0){
        if(!checkMail($(".nameOrMail").val())) {
            return "Please enter a valid mail address or name!";
        }
    } else {
        if($(".nameOrMail").val() === '') {
            return "Please enter a valid mail address or name!";
        }
    }
}
```

**Live demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/4dUyX/

Comment: Im using jQuery.validationEngine http://www.position-relative.net/creation/formValidator/ How can I add this to formValidator engine?

Comment: I've added this to my answer :)

Comment: [This documentation](http://www.position-absolute.com/articles/jquery-form-validator-because-form-validation-is-a-mess/) is pretty fine. There you'll find a lot of predefined expressions.

Comment: jQuery.validationEngine has this validation.. what if sir using a custom email is optional. if input contains @ then check for email validation otherwise check for name validation?

Comment: My fault. I've coded a few snippets, see above. Hope this helps.

Comment: No luck sir..Syntax Error in $("#nameOrMail").val() !== '' ? return true : return false;

Comment: Thank you so mucj dop-trois your the man! finally it's working! :)

Answer (score 0):

Use split function then you will not need regex

```
<script>
function check(email){
    if (email.split("@").length>0) {
        return true;
    }
   else return false;
}

check('jfvh@yahoo.com'); </script>
```